# Overwrite a file only if has larger size

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have this small code to send files to an S3 bucket:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (intent != null && intent.getStringExtra(INTENT_KEY_NAME) != null) {
        final String key = intent.getStringExtra(INTENT_KEY_NAME);
        final File file = (File) intent.getSerializableExtra(INTENT_FILE);
        final String transferOperation = intent.getStringExtra(INTENT_TRANSFER_OPERATION);
        TransferObserver transferObserver;

        switch (transferOperation) {
            case TRANSFER_OPERATION_DOWNLOAD:
                Log.d(TAG, "Downloading " + key);
                transferObserver = transferUtility.download("aws-mybucket", key, file);
                transferObserver.setTransferListener(new DownloadListener());
                break;
            case TRANSFER_OPERATION_UPLOAD:
                Log.d(TAG, "Uploading " + key);
                transferObserver = transferUtility.upload("aws-mybucket", key, file);
                transferObserver.setTransferListener(new UploadListener());
                break;
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    } else {
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

And this is my actual Bucket Policy:

```
{
"Version": "2008-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowPublicRead",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::aws-mybucket/*"
    }
]
}
```

When a file is sent, they simply overwrite the actual one. My question is: there is any bucket policy or bucket configuration that will let the overwrite happen only if the file sent is larger than the actual one? Thanks.

Comment: Bucket policy cant enforce that, your upload code would have to have that logic

Comment: That seems like an unusual requirement. I could understand "reject uploaded file if file already exists in S3" or "replace file in S3 if uploaded file is newer". Why is the larger size relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few ways to accomplish this from the client logic.

1) You can use the Versioning feature provided by Amazon S3. You can enable versioning on the bucket. You can send version along with the metadata during every upload. The downside is that you need to pay for maintaining multiple versions.

2) Before uploading a file, you can get the metadata of the object identified by the key name. The metadata (if the object identified by the key is present) contains lastModifiedTime and size. To your use-case, you can check for lastModifiedTime < currentTime and size < currentSize and do an upload that overwrites.